# Physical or logical backup takes more space when backing up same MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

Physical backup is copying the data files that belongs to database. Logical backup is using SQL statements.
So physical or logical backup takes more space when backing up same MySQL database?

Comment: *So physical or logical backup takes more space when backing up same MySQL database?* Unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

If you backup the files by copying the directory tree, the backup is the same size as the original.

If you use `mysqldump` (or similar tool) to backup, that will contain `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements to recreate the database from scratch.  This can be larger *or* smaller, depending on the data involved.

An example of "smaller": a `BIGINT` takes 8 bytes in a table, but if the value is `1`, it will take about 2 bytes in a logical dump (`1` and a comma).